# how to update across tables in Maria DB while avoiding "subquery: more than one row" error

Tags: php, mysql, select, mariadb

**Overview (code below):**

Within a Maria DB, I'm trying to update a value in table 1 based on a value in table 2, based on shared email addresses... and not succeeding.

**Here's the output I'm getting:**

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
UPDATE table1  
SET mytable1column=   
(SELECT mytable2column  
               FROM table2  
               WHERE table1.Email =table2.Email

               LIMIT 10000);
```

And to be more specific, I'm trying to

*insert into table1.mytable1column
the value from table2.mytable2column

*in all cases where an Email value in table1 also exists as an Email value in table2

Note that the email addresses in both tables are not unique; table1 may contain multiple instances of the same email, and table2 may also contain multiple instances of the same email.

What am I doing wrong, and what should I be doing instead?

Thanks! :)

**SOLUTION, via flauntster (in comments)**

UPDATE table1
SET mytable1column= (SELECT mytable2column   FROM table2   WHERE table1.Email =table2.Email
LIMIT 1);

Comment: you need to limit the number of results in the subquery, perhaps with a LIMIT clause, because you can only set the value in the parent query with a singular value.

Comment: Thanks! I got the same "more than 1 row" error after using this: UPDATE table1 SET mytable1column= (SELECT mytable2column 
FROM table2 
WHERE table1.Email =table2.Email
LIMIT 10000);

Comment: Because LIMIT 10000 can still return up to 10000 results, you'll want to LIMIT 1 :)

Comment: Use the "multi-table" `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: Re multi-table:
I'm using UPDATE table1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
       table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
   SET t1.value = t2.value  but this hasn't worked so far...